# What's the best method to catenate together multiple input parameters in Robot Framework?

Tags: url, concatenation, robotframework

I am trying to minimize my Robot Keywords and in my URL testing I sometimes have to build up a URL from a group of inputs, that can vary depending on the test.  The length can be anywhere from 4 to 7 input parameters that I am catenating to pass back one URL with whatever input parameters are passed in.

If I have a keyword that does the following:

```
inputs: ${location01} ${location02} ${location03}=${EMPTY} ${location04}=${EMPTY}
${my_url} = Catenate SEPARATOR=/ ${location01} ${location02} ${location03} ${location04}
[Return] ${my_url}
```

What is the best method to test if ${location03} is empty, and I can therefore skip the rest?

When I have tried to test for ${EMPTY}, so that the following will be false

```
${my_url} Run Keyword IF '${location03}'!='${EMPTY} Catenate SEPARATOR=/ ${location01} ${location02} ${location03} ${location04}
```

I still get a catenated string but end up with extra /'s at the end, so ${my_url} looks like:

```
${my_url} = ${location01}/${location02}//
```

When I want:

```
${my_url} = ${location01}/${location02}
```

I may be missing how Robot is doing checks, and initializing my variables, I'm sure there is a way to do this that is eluding me at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use @{args} to handle variable number of parameters:

```
*** Keywords ***
Create URL
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    ${url}=        Catenate    SEPARATOR=/        @{args}

*** Test Cases ***
Test Url
    Create URL     http://stackoverflow.com       questions      robotframework
    Create URL     http://stackoverflow.com       questions
```

Comment: You might want to add a `[return]` to your keyword.